# statement in function never evaluates as true

Tags: php

```
$button=$_GET['button'];    

function read2On(){
  $myFile = "light state.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
  $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
  fclose($fh);
  if($theData!="light is ON"){
    sleep(1);
    read2On();
  }
  else if($theData=="light is ON"){
    echo $theData;
  }
}

function read2Off(){
  $myFile = "light state.txt";
  $fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
  $theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
  fclose($fh);
  if($theData!="light is OFF"){        
    sleep(1);
    read2Off();
  }
  else if($theData=="light is OFF"){
    echo $theData;
  }
}

if($button=="lightTurnOn"){
  lightTurnOn();
  read2On();
}
else if($button=="lightTurnOff"){
  lightTurnOff();
  read2Off();
}
```

Function read2On() is called and executed as I expected but function read2Off is not. Statement in function body never evaluates as true, so function is calling self infinietly except from when value is true on first call. For completeness  function ligthTurnOff() which is called from same else if statement as function read2Off() is called and executed properly. Where should be a problem?

Comment: sadly, we have no idea what's in your file.

Comment: In my file is light is OFF or light is ON. When message "lightTurnOff" arrives and in file is "light is OFF" it´s OK even If message "lightTurnOn" arrives and in file is "light is OFF" and then I change it for "light is On" program works as I expect. Problem is when message is  "lightTurnOff", in file "light is On" then "light is OFF".

Comment: Ok,after some trial I thing is something with length of evaluated strings, as Light turn OF vs Light turn ON, or I vs O are working.

Answer (score 0):

Value of filesize($myFile) was cached thus fread() was assigning bad number of characters to $theData. Calling clearstatcache() solved The problem.

Comment: or you can just use `$theData = file_get_contents($myFile);` see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-get-contents.php)